# Multithreading Performance in MATLAB C API

Tags: c, multithreading, performance, matlab

I was reading the article [Multi-threaded Mex](https://web.archive.org/web/20190911150448/http://undocumentedmatlab.com:80/blog/multi-threaded-mex) from [Undocumented Matlab](https://undocumentedmatlab.com/matlab/wp-content/cache/all/index.html) and decided to benchmark the given example (a `max(a,b)` function without an explicit output; the function updates `a` in-place with the maximal values from corresponding indices of the both matrices).

[image]

The multithreading starts to show its power for matrices with more than 1 million elements (1000 x 1000 matrix, for example). For small matrices, since the main function is very simple (a for-loop and an if-statement to copy the values from `b` to `a` if `b[i] > a[i]`), we have basically the time necessary for creating the threads. I was expecting that the multithreading would be slower in this context, but not that slower (more than hundred of times). So I decided to come here and ask if those results are reasonable.

The .c file can be found in [MATLAB's File Exchange](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/68237-max_in_place-example-of-multi-threaded-mex-function) and the benchmark routine was the following.

```
function t = max_in_place_tester(r,n,~)

if nargin < 1   
    r = [1e3,5e2,1e2,1e2,1e1,1e0,1e0,1e0];   
    r = [r.',r.'].';    
    r = r(1:(end-1));    
end

if isempty(r)    
    r = 1;    
end

if nargin < 2
    
    m = maxNumCompThreads;
    
    n = [1e1,1e2,1e3,1e4,1e5,1e6,1e7,1e8];   
    n = [n.',5*n.'].';   
    n = n(1:(end-1));
    
    t = zeros(m,size(n,2));
    
    if size(r,2) == 1        
        r = repmat(r,1,size(n,2));        
    end
    
    for i = 1:size(n,2)        
        t(:,i) = max_in_place_tester(r(i),n(i),[]);       
    end
    
    n = log10(n);
    
    t = t ./ r(1,:);
    %t = t ./ t(1,:);
    
    figure('Color','White');
    hold on, grid on;
    xlabel('log10(Number of Elements)');
    ylabel('Relative Time Spent');
    
    for i = 1:m
        plot(n,t(i,:)./t(1,:),'LineWidth',2.5,'DisplayName',sprintf('Number of Threads: %d',i));
    end
    
    legend;
    
else
    
    m = maxNumCompThreads;
    
    n = round(sqrt(n));
    
    t = zeros(m,1);
    
    a = rand(n,n);
    b = rand(n,n);
    c = a;
    d = b;
    %getaddress(a,b,c,d)
    c(1,1) = a(1,1);
    d(1,1) = b(1,1);
    %getaddress(a,b,c,d)
    
    for i = 1:m
        
        a = c;
        b = d;
        %getaddress(a,b,c,d)
        a(1,1) = c(1,1);
        b(1,1) = d(1,1);
        %getaddress(a,b,c,d)
        
        maxNumCompThreads(i);
        
        if nargin > 2
            
            s = tic;
            for j = 1:r
                max_in_place(a,b);
            end
            t(i,1) = toc(s);
            
        else
            
            fprintf('Number of Threadings: %d\n',maxNumCompThreads);
            
            tic;
            for j = 1:r
                max_in_place(a,b);
            end
            toc;
            
        end
        
    end
    
end

end
```

Comment: What do you expect to get as an answer in this question? "Is it reasonable?" "Yes". You might want to [edit] an actual question into your post, something that would give you the information you're looking for when answered. Yes/no questions are not really useful in general.

Comment: What was your first thought after looking at those results? Suppose they were obtained from a routine written by you. What would be your next step? "That's completely normal; I will add an if-statement to run the main loop without multi-threading when (number_of_elements < 1e6)" or "There is something odd; I should take a look at the multi-threading library documentation and try to figure out what is going on". Those results say nothing to me. I don't have any sensibility about them. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to ask an actual question. Right now the answer is “yes, it’s normal”, but that is too short to submit as an answer. And it’s likely not what you came here for.

Comment: Also, there are much better ways of doing multithreading that don’t require manually creating threads. Libraries can do that for you. Look for example for OpenMP, a compiler extension that handles multithreading. That’s the simplest to use solution I know.